# IPV4 header checksum verification

Tags: networking

When a packet is sent from source to destination,it has to pass by through several routers and each router decreases the value of TTL of packet by 1. So header checksum is to be recomputed at each router since one of the header field i.e. TTL surely changes. Then how does the destination verifies the presence of error by calculating the checksum ,though the checksum it got has changed than that of checksum of source side?

Answer (score 2):

When the packet leaves the source, it has some initial TTL and (hopefully) a valid checksum.

When the packet arrives at a router, the router checks only the IPv4 header checksum. If it is incorrect, it drops the packet. If it is correct, it (1) decrements the TTL; (2) checks that the TTL is higher than zero (otherwise the packet is dropped) and (3) computes and fills in the new IP header checksum.

Interestingly, the new checksum can be computed directly from the old checksum and the old and new value of the TTL, with some clever math: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1624 so reading the whole IPv4 header again is not necessary.

Note that IPv6 has a hop limit (which works like the TTL) but no header checksum.

Comment: tnx for the correct order, of the router operations! One more question if that's ok. If the ttl=0 and there is a checksum problem in the 16 bit header does this mean that ICMP will send to the source the TTL error? because of the operations order in the router?

Comment: The checksum verification is performed first. The exact algorithm is described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1812.txt section 5.2.1.1. While it is a bit old (1995), according to http://www.ietf.org/download/rfc-index.txt it still applies ("Status: BEST CURRENT PRACTICE").

Answer (score 1):

Every router calculates and verifies the checksum before routing, if there is a mismatch the router drops the datagram.

Comment: It means that first the router verifies the checksum and then only  it changes the TTL value and recomputes the checksum value.

Comment: @Shubhamverma, yes. More than that, if the checksum is not correct it just drops it. if it is correct, the router processes it: checks the routing table and learns the next hop, it decreases TTL, recomputes checksum and then it sends it out to the next hop. In general, checksum calculation is offloaded to the NIC for performance reasons.